# How to check my API URL SSL and NON-SSL support in Android app?

Tags: android, http, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have an android app and some response from URLs, that URL contains SSL supporting also `NON-SSL` support `URLS`.
now i write the code for SSL support and working nicely. i want to check both a conditions 
if `SSL` and `NON-SSL` site also supoorted.

what i tryied here,

```
String url = AdRequestParam.getURL();
HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;  
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

//SSL
SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(client.getParams(), registry);
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, client.getParams());

// Set verifier     
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can fix this issues y using `url.startsWith("http://")`, to write the condition and make then execute as per the requesting URLs.